# Error correcting codes for asymmetric channels

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

Most work in error correction coding theory (Hamming, Cyclic, BCH, Reed-Solomon, Turbo Codes, LDPC...) deals with **linear codes**. Now, a linear code binary code is a good fit (only?) for a **symmetric channel**.

I wonder: isn't this a strong requirement, and a severe limitation? Is there some way that one can adapt the enormous body of work on linear codes when using a asymmetric channel?

I find it rather strange that most textbooks hardly speak of this issue (perhaps in practice most channels are symmetric?). Some discussion or references?

Comment: I know that work has been done on the [Z channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Z-channel_%28information_theory%29&oldid=635825539). The [first reference](http://www.ii.uib.no/~torleiv/rap95.pdf) at the bottom of that page looks promising.